# How to resolve PMD issue in STS

Tags: java, pmd

```
AppCommonUtils.optional(customerVO.getPincode()).map(Integer::valueOf).map(mstPincodeCityRepository::findCityByPincode).ifPresent(mstPincode -> {
    mstAddress.setPincode(customerVO.getPincode());
    mstAddress.setMstCity(mstPincode.getMstCity());
});
```

> For above code PMD showing :: Potential violation of Law of Demeter
>   (method chain calls)

Can someone please suggest how to remove this warning PMD message?

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies on `AppCommonUtils.optional`. That method is returning an object you didn't create directly, and are then manipulating, which is a violation for this rule.

See: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.10.0/pmd_rules_java_design.html#lawofdemeter

As that is a factory method, this behavior is by design and not a problem. I'd suggest you simply [suppress it](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.10.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html)